# Globally add selector to all my CSS selector with Webpack (at build time)

Tags: sass, webpack, css-selectors, css-loader, sass-loader

I would like to globally append a specific selector to all CSS selector used in my application.

I'm using React and those Webpack loaders `post-css`, `css-loader`, `sass-loader` and `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

I don't want to edit all my classname within jsx files. I just want to append this specific selector **at build time**.

Is there a loader to achieve this? Or any other solution...

What I actually have:

```
.myClass {
  ...

  &--blue { ... }
}
```

What I want after Webpack transpilation:

```
.specificClass .myClass { ... }
.specificClass .myClass--blue { ... }
```

Thanks

Gautier

PS: The reason I need this feature is to avoid CSS selector collision with the Website I'm integrating my application. I don't wan't to manually edit all my scss files to append the selector.

Answer (score 0):

this should be solvable by in you main sass file:

```
.specificClass {
    @import 'variables';
    @import 'fonts';
    // ... do more imports
}
```

Comment: I don't have single sass entry point. I import all my scss files directly on React components.